# android layout with aspect ratio cant show childs which refers to parent

Tags: android, android-layout, onmeasure

im trying to make a `RelativeLayout` with aspect ratio 2:1. Layout is resizing properly and also `ImageView` in this `RelativeLayout` looks good. But `TextView` isnt visible, and that is because of attribute  `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` Using any of attributes which aligns, centers etc. of parent causes that view isnt visible. How to fix that ?

MyRelativeLayout:

```
 @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(widthMeasureSpec/2, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}

<com.stikyapp.MyRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@color/green"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:text="textView1"/>

</com.stikyapp.MyRelativeLayout>
```

If im using aspect ratio 1:1 which is square it all works with this code

```
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
```

Comment: Not sure what is causing your issue, perhaps you should digg the RelativeLayout code. As a workaround you may try to wrap your TextView with the FrameLayout which has match_parent dimensions and center the TextView inside that FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [AspectRatioLayout](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/AspectRatioLayout)

```
<com.sherlock.aspectratio.AspectRatioLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:widthHeightRatio="2" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- your imageview -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.sherlock.aspectratio.AspectRatioLayout>
```